# How to avoid `loaded two copies of React` error when developing an external component?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am developing an external component (let's say `my-component`, which I link to the project with `npm link` (as it is in process and I need the package to reflect changes).

In the `my-component` folder there are `node_modules/react` and `node_modules/react-dom` as they are its dependencies. However they are peerDependences, so I did not suppose to bring them into the project linking this package.

However when using `npm link`, it link the whole directory, including `node_modules`. So, when the project builds, it includes packages 2 times: from `node_modules/*` and from `node_modules/my-component/node_modules/*`.

This begins to affect when the component is using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`, it causes this error:

```
Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.0.2.0`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.
```

Also, it may help to understand what's happening: the problem only appears if there are both `node_modules/my-component/node_modules/react` and `node_modules/my-component/node_modules/react-dom`. If there is only one of them, there is no error message.

The usual package installation does not bring such error as there is no `node_modules/react-dom` there.

How is it supposed to develop an external component and the project at the same time?

Comment: I've been having the same problem and have resorted to using `React.render` and `React.findDOMNode` and ignoring the deprecation warnings. As long as I don't `require`/`import` `react-dom`, I don't get this error.

Comment: Also, this is not specific to `npm link`, it will happen to you once you `npm install` that component you're developing as well.

Comment: So my problem ended up being much different than yours -- I was rolling up my deps separate from the rest of my assets, and missed `react-dom` in my list of deps to roll up separately. Since `react-dom` depends on `react`, I ended up with two copies, one in my deps rollup and one in my main application bundle. More [here](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/react-dom-does-not-work-with-external-components-that-use-react/2359/6?u=ericsoco).

Comment: @Varvara Stephanova: Have you found a solution to this? It seems like i'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Varvara Stephanova http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398396/de-duplicate-libraries-in-app-within-deeply-nested-node-modules

Answer (score 21):

The issue is twofold:

1. You cannot have 2 copies of react loaded.
2. npm link creates a symlink, however the "require" doesnt respect the
   symlink and when it tries to navigate up the directory, it never
   finds the react of the parent project.

Solution:

All you have to do is link the react and react-dom in your component to that of parent project's node_modules folder.

Go to your component project and remove the react and react-dom then do

```
npm link ../myproject/node_modules/react
npm link ../myproject/node_modules/react-dom
```

Comment: It works. But it's confusing on number 2 of your statement. Based on my understanding, when you load the package in the main project, it will create a React instance which is different to main project and this is not allowed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Had the same problem but with yarn, doing similar yarn links to the original repos react/react-dom also solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This solution works. Pay attention to: you link from external component to main project /node_modules. Other way around this doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Fixed it by adding `react-dom` as an alias to my webpack config

```
alias: {

    react$: require.resolve(path.join(constants.NODE_MODULES_DIR, 'react')),
    'react-dom': require.resolve(path.join(constants.NODE_MODULES_DIR, 'react-dom'))

}
```

Comment: This seems like a dirty hack, but it worked for me. Thanks! :)

Comment: any idea why name it the keys `react$` and `'react-dom'`? would it make sense to name them `React` and `ReactDOM`?

Comment: This works great. In my case, the parent project is only linking this development purposes, so it won't be there in production, but even if it was, it would still work great.

Answer (score 6):

Someone clevererer than I (@mojodna) came up with this solution: remove the duplicate dependencies from the external component, and resolve them with your project's copies of those deps.

**Step 1: Remove the dependencies from your external component's `node_modules`**

As [@cleong noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157904/how-to-avoid-loaded-two-copies-of-react-error-when-developing-an-external-comp#comment55101981_33448574), you can't just remove the deps from the external component's `node_modules`, because your project's build step will fail when it hits the now-missing dependencies in the external component.

**Step 2: Add your project's `node_modules` to `NODE_PATH`**

To fix this, you can append the project's `node_modules` to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable when running your build step. Something like e.g. this:

`NODE_PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/ npm start`

(where `npm start` is your script that bundles your external component, via e.g. Browserify, Webpack, etc.)

In fact, you could always append that `NODE_PATH` addition to your build scripts, and it would work whether or not you've `npm link`ed anything. (Makes me wonder if it shouldn't be default `npm` behavior...)

*Note: I left my existing answer because there's some conversation there, and this is a different (and better) solution.*

Comment: This is genius. It really should become a part of npm.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer is to specify `react` and `react-dom` as `peerDependencies` in your external component's `package.json`. As best as I can follow [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5080) and [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565#issuecomment-74971689), `npm link` should (as of `npm@3`) no longer install `peerDependencies` (or `devDependencies either).

Aaaand I just read your post more carefully and realized that you already are specifying them as `peerDependencies`. Therefore, I think the answer boils down to:

**Upgrade to `npm@3`:**

`npm install -g npm@3.0-latest`

Comment: If react and react-dom aren't in the component's node_modules, browserify will fail to find them (for some reason). You have to create symlinks to the project's copies.

Comment: Of course, if the linked component is shared by different projects though, then the symlinks will only be correct for one of them. You can't even have two copies of the component, since npm only lets you link to one copy. The situation is kinda fubar at the moment. The only good solution is to use npm private module.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with npm link.  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5875

npm doesn't treat the linked directory as a child of the parent project.

Try alternatives to npm link:

1) Use relative path dependencies in package.json

2) Manually include your dependencies in your projects node_modules directory

3) Use url path

Basically anything but npm link

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following in my `webpack.config.js` worked for me:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        react: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
    }
}
```

I also experimented with `DedupePlugin` (mentioned as a possible remedy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33402061/274677)) but I couldn't get it to work.

What's also interesting is that I've encountered different (and perhaps more insidious) manifestations of the same problem when a module is found in multiple places in the dependency graph.

One such case was that my `React.PropTypes.instanceOf(SomeType)` constraints would emit warnings even though the type I passed in was correct. That was due to the module being present in multiple places in the `node_modules` directory tree. Due to duck-typing the code would still work, but my console was cluttered with these warnings. Going the `resolve.alias` way silenced those too.

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

I am using [ReactJS.net](http://reactjs.net/) and setup webpack from the tutorial there and started using `react-bootstrap` aswell when i started getting this error. I found adding `'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'` to the list of `externals` in `webpack.config.js` fixed the problem, the list of externals then looked like this:

```
  externals: {
    // Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
    // bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
      react: 'React',
      'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
```

This seems to be the first stack overflow link on google for this error, so i thought this answer might help someone here.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend using https://github.com/mweststrate/relative-deps.

> Installs dependencies from a local checkout, and keeps them in sync, without the limitations of link.

This fixes the issue as it installs the local library just as npm install would, satisfying any dependency versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Webpack in the main project, [this solution](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#npm-linked-modules-don-t-find-their-dependencies) may work. In my case, `project-a` requires `project-b`. Both require React and ReactDOM 0.14.x

I have this in `project-a/webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
},
resolveLoader: {
  fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
},
```

- `project-b` requires React and ReactDOM as `peerDependencies` in `project-b/package.json`
- `project-a` requires `project-b` as a `devDependency` (should also work required as a `dependency`) in `project-a/package.json`
- local `project-b` is linked to `project-a` like so: `cd project-a; npm link ../project-b`

Now when I run `npm run build` within `project-b`, the changes appear immediately in `project-a`

Comment: Have you updated this in 2022 ? Seems like the webpack config changed a bit

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because I had already included `react` and `react-dom` as external scripts in my HTML markup.

The error was caused by adding an `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` to a component module. The error went away once I removed the import, and the module worked fine since the components were already available.