# Webpack keeps including node_modules from dependencies when they are already in main vendor file

Tags: npm, webpack, lerna

I'm using a self made component library to share components between my projects. The problem is that even after using the [**Authoring libraries**](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) guide by `webpack` it keeps including those dependencies in my main build and I am out of ideas on what setting that this is caused by...

**Build analysis (when bundling my app)**

Here you can see the `node_modules` and `wizer-components/node_modules`. Including `react-dom` twice (and others)

[image]

**Build analysis (of a component)**

As you can see no node_modules are bundled here...

[image]

**Setting files**

Because I can't find where the issue lies I have created [gists of my config files](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/3c5b406ffb4f77b74698f7db41cad3f9):

- `webpack.config.js` (of component library)
- `webpack.config.production.js` (of app)

**Setup**

Just as info, I'm using a monorepo setup with [`lerna`](https://lernajs.io/) to `npm link` the dependency of (wizer-components) without the need to push it to `npm` as a module. Could this be an issue in where webpack thinks that it needs to re-add the `react` (and others)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a total of 4 days of trying to make this work (was doing this before I asked the question), I managed to solve it (FINALLY)!

The issue was with lerna / NPM link and dependency resolving, see handy links at the bottom of this answer.

I fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. Moving the `dependencies` (`react`, `react-dom`) to `peerDependencies` in the `wizer-components` (my component library) `package.json` file
2. Removing all my `node_modules` folders (app and component library)
3. Running `$ lerna bootstrap` to re-download my `node_modules`
4. Removing my build process of my component library (I build these when I build my app)
5. Changing my `webpack.config.production.js` in these key areas

(did a picture because it wouldn't format it right on here -_-

[image]

Helpful links (also look at the comments):

- [How to avoid React loading twice with Webpack when developing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169760/how-to-avoid-react-loading-twice-with-webpack-when-developing/38818358#38818358)
- [npm link doesn't play nice with peer dependencies](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5875)
- [How to avoid `loaded two copies of React` error when developing an external component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157904/how-to-avoid-loaded-two-copies-of-react-error-when-developing-an-external-comp/)

Comment: Always remember that when webpack searches for js files to bundle, it searches *all* folders in your project by default unless you explicitly tell it to include or exclude certain paths. Feel free to mark this as solved. :)

Comment: Man, you saved my life here. Your fix helped me solve a completely different problem (fixing a problem where babel wasn't transpiling prebuild dependencies) -- my fix was to remove the exclusion of node_modules from the babel rule (perhaps unrelated, though it sparked the idea). But what I really wanted to upvote you for was your honesty about spending 4 days to solve the problem. Well done. Most people would underestimate that by a lot I suspect. More might have just given up.